# Animate and play sounds in Simon Says 'the Angular way'

Tags: javascript, recursion, angular.js, dom, simon-says

I am a newbie coder and I'm trying to learn good coding habits.  I'm making a Simon Says game challenge from Free Code Camp in Angular JS.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/sharonghae/pen/dXOprE)

I have an array that keeps random integers between 1-4:

```
var simonSays = [];
```

This is how I'm currently animating and playing sounds.  I've read that you're not to manipulate the DOM using Angular.  But how would I handle it for my game?

```
var counter = 0, //for looping thru simon's array
    innerTimeOutSecs = 1000, //time during each iteration
    outerTimeOutSecs = 500, //time before next iteration
    simonTurn = false; //if simon is playing, player cannot interrupt simon

function animateSimonSays() {
    simonTurn = true;
    $timeout(function() {
        var simon = simonSays[counter];
        //find the current pad and current audio to light up/play
        var currentPad = document.getElementById("pad" + simon);
        var currentAudio = document.getElementById("pad" + simon + "_audio");
        angular.element(currentPad).addClass("lightUpPad");
        currentAudio.play();

        $timeout(function() {
            currentAudio.pause(); //stop audio
            currentAudio.currentTime = 0;
            angular.element(currentPad).removeClass("lightUpPad"); //'turn off' pad

            //get ready for the next simon
            counter++;
            if (counter < simonSays.length) { //recursion fail condition
                animateSimonSays();
            } else {
                counter = 0;
                simonTurn = false;
            }
        }, innerTimeOutSecs); //how long to stay 'lit'
    }, outerTimeOutSecs); //how long before the next simon
}
```

It's dirty but it works for my app.  All the examples I found online were jQuery so I couldn't really follow their methodology.

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
  var simonSays = [], //push what simon says
    copy = [], // compare user answer to simon answer
    counter = 0, //for looping thru simon's array
    innerTimeOutSecs = 1000, //time during each iteration
    outerTimeOutSecs = 500, //delay in resetting to original state of pad and call next pad
    simonTurn = false, //if simon is playing, play cannot interrupt simon
    currentResponse = true; //used to compare user answer to simon

  $scope.count = 0; //number of rounds
  $scope.isStrict = false; //is strict mode on/off

  $scope.startGame = function() { //start button calls restart
    restart();
  }

  function restart() { //initialize game by setting values in array to empty and start a new round
    simonSays = [];
    $scope.count = 0;
    newRound();
  }

  function newRound() { //begin next round 
    if ($scope.count === 20) { //victory alert if player reaches 20 steps
      alert("Congratulations. You win!");
      restart();
      return;
    }
    $scope.count++; //increase round by one
    if ($scope.count % 5 === 0) {
      innerTimeOutSecs -=100;
      outerTimeOutSecs -=50;
    }
    simonSays.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1)); //add random step to the end
    copy = simonSays.slice(0);
    animateSimonSays();
  }

  function animateSimonSays() { //light works and sound 

    //TODO: speedup animations after every 5 'count'
    simonTurn = true; //simon is playing, user cannot play function again by pressin start
    $timeout(function() { //outertimeout

      var simon = simonSays[counter]; //setting up iteration of array
      var currentPad = document.getElementById("pad" + simon); //setting up light show for each 
      var currentAudio = document.getElementById("pad" + simon + "_audio"); //setup audio
      angular.element(currentPad).addClass("lightUpPad"); //opacity change
      currentAudio.play(); //audio starts

      $timeout(function() { //inner timeout
        currentAudio.pause(); //stop sound
        currentAudio.currentTime = 0; //set audio back to start position
        angular.element(currentPad).removeClass("lightUpPad"); //return to original opacity 

        counter++; //setting up next iteration in array 

        if (counter < simonSays.length) { //test for recursiveness
          animateSimonSays(); //calling recursive function for next iteration
        } else { //if counter reaches end..
          counter = 0; //reset counter
          simonTurn = false; //simon turn over
        }
      }, innerTimeOutSecs); //how long it stays lit

    }, outerTimeOutSecs); //next pad

  }

  //three possible situations
  //1.user click wrong pad --> call animate again (last round)
  //2.user click right pad but seq not finish --> do nothing
  //3.user pick right pad and end of seq --> new round
  function checkResponse() {
    if (!currentResponse) { // case 1
      var buzzer = document.getElementById("buzzer");
      buzzer.play();

      if ($scope.isStrict) { //strict mode restarts game
        $timeout(function() {
          buzzer.pause();
          buzzer.currentTime = 0;
          restart();
        }, 1000);
        return;
      }

      $timeout(function() {
        buzzer.pause();
        buzzer.currentTime = 0;
        copy = simonSays.slice(0);
        animateSimonSays();
      }, 1000);

    } else if (currentResponse && copy.length === 0) { //case 3
      $timeout(newRound, 1000);

    }
  }

  $scope.registerClick = function(padId) {
    if (simonTurn) return; //click does not register during simon turn
    //var currentPad = document.getElementById("pad" + padId);
    var currentAudio = document.getElementById("pad" + padId + "_audio");
    currentAudio.play();

    $timeout(function() {
      currentAudio.pause();
      currentAudio.currentTime = 0;
    }, 500);

    var desiredResponse = copy.shift(); //pop out first index of the array
    var actualResponse = padId;
    currentResponse = desiredResponse === actualResponse; //compare click and simon
    checkResponse();
  }

}]);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 310px;
}

.pad {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pad:active {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.shape1 {
  border-top-left-radius: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

.shape2 {
  float: left;
  border-top-right-radius: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  clear: right;
}

.shape3 {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  clear: left;
}

.shape4 {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 195px;
  left: 195px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 125px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.simon {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-size: 5em;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.startButton {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.strictButton {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ffff00;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.strictIndicator {
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  background-color: #32050C;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.strictIndicator-on {
  background-color: #DC0D29;
}

.lightUpPad {
  opacity: 1;
}

.count {
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #32050C;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #DC0D29;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  border: 2px solid #222;
}

.controllabel {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

.countlabel {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.buttonlabel {
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.controls {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

.strictlabel {
  margin-top: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<audio preload="auto" id="pad1_audio"><source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<audio preload="auto" id="pad2_audio"><source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<audio preload="auto" id="pad3_audio"><source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<audio preload="auto" id="pad4_audio"><source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<audio preload="auto" id="buzzer"><source src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/Basketball Buzzer-SoundBible.com-1863250611.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="back">
      <div id="pad1" class="pad shape1" ng-click="registerClick(1)">
      </div>

      <div id="pad2" class="pad shape2" ng-click="registerClick(2)">
      </div>

      <div id="pad3" class="pad shape3" ng-click="registerClick(3)">
      </div>

      <div id="pad4" class="pad shape4" ng-click="registerClick(4)">
      </div>

      <div class="circle">
        <div class="simon">simon</div>
        <div class="controls">
          <div class="count">{{count}}</div>
          <div class="controllabel countlabel">COUNT</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="controls">
          <button class="startButton" ng-click="startGame()"></button>
          <div class="controllabel buttonlabel">START</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="controls">
          <div ng-class="isStrict ? 'strictIndicator-on' : ''" class="strictIndicator"></div>
          <button class="strictButton" ng-click="isStrict = !isStrict"></button>
          <div class="controllabel strictlabel">STRICT</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you include the html?

Comment: @Pimgd Working codepen is here: http://codepen.io/sharonghae/pen/dXOprE

Comment: then I cant review, code has to be in the question due to legal issues

Comment: @Pimgd I added the full code into the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your controller could store a "padToLightUp" value. Then use `ng-class={'lightUpPad': padToLightUp == 1}` (where 1 is the pad number, so it could be 1, or 2, 3, 4...). This gets rid of the need to find a pad in the dom to light up.

Similarily, you could store the audio references all in an array, so that you can hook a `selectPad` function to the pad's `ng-click`, in which you play the audio file.

Lastly, instead of wrapping everything in `timeout`, make them actual functions that stand separately. Then you can use `$timeout(lightUpNextPad)`, which means that the use of timeout affects your code structure far less.

---

```
//1.user click wrong pad --> call animate again (last round)
//2.user click right pad but seq not finish --> do nothing
//3.user pick right pad and end of seq --> new round
function checkResponse() {
  if (!currentResponse) { // case 1
    var buzzer = document.getElementById("buzzer");
    buzzer.play();

    if ($scope.isStrict) { //strict mode restarts game
      $timeout(function() {
        buzzer.pause();
        buzzer.currentTime = 0;
        restart();
      }, 1000);
      return;
    }

    $timeout(function() {
      buzzer.pause();
      buzzer.currentTime = 0;
      copy = simonSays.slice(0);
      animateSimonSays();
    }, 1000);

  } else if (currentResponse && copy.length === 0) { //case 3
    $timeout(newRound, 1000);

  }
}
```

This function is rather messy - there are three cases, but the comments only mention 2. And the random return in the middle there seems like weird flow. Let's fix it.

First, replace the `return` with `else`.

```
//1.user click wrong pad --> call animate again (last round)
//2.user click right pad but seq not finish --> do nothing
//3.user pick right pad and end of seq --> new round
function checkResponse() {
  if (!currentResponse) { // case 1
    var buzzer = document.getElementById("buzzer");
    buzzer.play();

    if ($scope.isStrict) { //strict mode restarts game
      $timeout(function() {
        buzzer.pause();
        buzzer.currentTime = 0;
        restart();
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      $timeout(function() {
        buzzer.pause();
        buzzer.currentTime = 0;
        copy = simonSays.slice(0);
        animateSimonSays();
      }, 1000);
    }
  } else if (currentResponse && copy.length === 0) { //case 3
    $timeout(newRound, 1000);
  }
}
```

Next, you have `if(!currentResponse){ ... } else if(currentResponse && ...` - that second check for `currentResponse` is not needed.

```
//1.user click wrong pad --> call animate again (last round)
//2.user click right pad but seq not finish --> do nothing
//3.user pick right pad and end of seq --> new round
function checkResponse() {
  if (!currentResponse) { // case 1
    var buzzer = document.getElementById("buzzer");
    buzzer.play();

    if ($scope.isStrict) { //strict mode restarts game
      $timeout(function() {
        buzzer.pause();
        buzzer.currentTime = 0;
        restart();
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      $timeout(function() {
        buzzer.pause();
        buzzer.currentTime = 0;
        copy = simonSays.slice(0);
        animateSimonSays();
      }, 1000);
    }
  } else if (copy.length === 0) { //case 3
    $timeout(newRound, 1000);
  }
}
```

You have multiple cases in your code where you have to "reset an audio element". This is done by calling `pause` and setting it's `currentTime` to 0.

You should make a separate function for that:

```
function stopAudio(audioElement) {
  audioElement.pause();
  audioElement.currentTime = 0;
}
```

Then you can use it for `buzzer`.

```
function checkResponse() {
  if (!currentResponse) { // case 1
    var buzzer = document.getElementById("buzzer");
    buzzer.play();

    if ($scope.isStrict) { //strict mode restarts game
      $timeout(function() {
        stopAudio(buzzer);
        restart();
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      $timeout(function() {
        stopAudio(buzzer);
        copy = simonSays.slice(0);
        animateSimonSays();
      }, 1000);
    }
  } else if (copy.length === 0) { //case 3
    $timeout(newRound, 1000);
  }
}
```